# How can I get React Developer Tool to Work with Genymotion

Tags: android, react-native, windows-7-x64, genymotion, react-devtools

The instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools), or React Native's official [site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools). And I was expecting to get something like this as shown on the official site:
[image]

**Whereas the reality is:**

I run the command to install the devtool locally into my project:
`npm install --save-dev react-devtools`

Add one line to "scripts" node in package.json:
`"react-devtools": "react-devtools"`

So, it looks like:
[image]

Then I start up the Genymotion emulator, and have a cmd window running `react-native start`, another cmd window running `npm run react-devtools`, which will open up the standalone tool:

[image]

And I have a third cmd window running `react-native run-android`. That will open a debugging tab in Chrome. However, nothing happens in the Developer Tool.
 And I cannot find $r in the devtool of Chrome:
[image]

I thought it might be because the emulator talks to packager server which is `localhost:8081`. But if I change that setting to: `192.168.1.2:8097`, as stated in Developer Tool:

[image]

I cannot even run the app in the emulator, it always stops like shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Has anyone managed to run it on Windows? Any help is appreciated, thanks.